# Shared disk users overwriting

Tags: .net, file-io

.NET application that runs on Citrix

For integration with a DLL I write to disk and the DLL reads it

```
c:\temp\files.txt
```

Clearly the problem there is another user could write before the DLL reads
Or the file is in use

I pass the file location to the DLL
The name is not fixed.

Users logon to Domain

Is there a user disk space that my program can access as well as the DLL

My other option is to just include the userID in the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a number of options available for doing this.  One simple one would be to [use `System.IO.Path` to create a temporary file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) in the host system and return that file name:

```
var fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
```

This way the host system handles the uniqueness of the file.  Then you can use that file for the duration of the user's session, and it will eventually get cleaned up by the system for you.